# Why the int takes a value that I have not assigned?

Tags: java

I'm very new in the world of Java. In this code I need to sort in an array the letters of the String str based on the number that they have before them. The int num stands for the index of the Array and the char char1 stands for the letter.

This is the code:

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str = "1a2b3c4d";
     Character[] example = new Character[str.length()];

     char char1 = ' ';
     int num = 0;
     int i = 0;
     int j = 1;
     
     num = num(str, num, i);
     char1 = char1(str, char1, j);
     
     System.out.println(num+" "+char1);

     example[num] = char1;
    }
    
    public static int num(String str, int num, int i) {
        i = i+2;
        num = str.charAt(i);
        return num;
    }
    
    public static char char1(String str, char char1, int j) {
        char1 = str.charAt(j);
        j = j+2;
        return char1;
    }
}
```

and this returns:

```
50 a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 50 out of bounds for length 8
     at example.main(example.java:17)
```

Why num has the value of 50?

Comment: You're using a conversion of `char` to `int`, which gives it the Unicode value. The char `'2'` has a Unicode value of 50.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! But how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Apart from the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` there are other issues in the code. What for do you increment arguments `i` and `j` in the methods `num` / `char1`?  These changes won't be visible outside the scope of these methods.  Are you aware that array indexes start from 0 and therefore `example[0]` will always be holding `null`?

Answer (score 1):

The integer value of a char is its [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) value. 50 is the Unicode value of the character '2'.

If you want to convert a character into its "real world" numeric value, then there are a couple of options:

- For a single character that you known is a digit, you can generally simply subtract 48 from the int value of the character-- the digits 0-9 translate to Unicode values 48-57.
- To cope with multiple digits in a string, look at the Integer.parseInt() method.

The Unicode values 0-127 generally correspond to their equivalent [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values. Whilst there's no need to remember the entire ASCII table, it's worth remembering a few key values that can then help you pick up on when this kind of issue occurs (space = 32, A-Z start at 65, digits start at 48; non-printable control characters occupy 0-31).

Comment: I've updated my answer: in your specific case, you can probably just subtract 48 from the value if you know for sure you're just dealing with a single digit. Otherwise, consider using Integer.parseInt() on the relevant substring of the original string.

Comment: Or `Character.digit`, potentially.

Comment: @JonSkeet, [`Character::getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) seems to be more appropriate :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko: I considered that, but I suspect the OP wants to restrict it to base 10.